# How to resize image in C# without smoothing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, optimization

How do you re-size a black and white image without any smoothing affect?   I have a BarCode that is an image that is too big.  I need to resize the image but with one caveat.  The resulting image needs to be the same proportional size and the black and white bars can not turn into black,grey and white bars(which I believe is due to some smoothing occuring).  Any example of how to do this in c#??

Comment: Harpo and arul were correct.  I was able to get rid of smoothing but that didn't fix the problem as the bar widths are no longer the same proportionally so I must solve this some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@arul is correct.  To be specific,

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
graphics.DrawImage( barCodeImage, new Point( 0, 0 ) );
```

You might also want to check out the InterpolationMode, to see whether changing this value gives you results closer to what you want.

Comment: Combine with graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

Answer (score 2):

You can specify [the smoothing mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode(VS.71).aspx) in the underlying [Graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You might want something like:

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

Comment: This ended up being what I needed.

Comment: Awesome. This is the correct answer. I didn't even consider trying NearestNeighbour. +1 * 10