# Increase image size by power of two without smoothing

Tags: c++, qt, imagemagick, image-resizing

In C++, or through a Linux shell script, how can I up-size an image by powers of 2 (e.g. a 40x60 image to 80x120) without any interpolation, so it comes out with a crisp pixelated looks like in the following image. Whenever I do it using Magick++'s `Image` or Qt's `QImage`, it applies smoothing to the resulting image.

[image: Pixelated image]

PS: There's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936210/how-to-resize-image-in-c-sharp-without-smoothing) that covers this for C#.

Comment: how did you use `QImage`?? can you post a line of code?

Comment: It looks like I was using QImage incorrectly, I added the correct code as one of the responses to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ImageMagick installed, a shell-script friendly option would be `mogrify -scale 200% image.png` This uses linear resampling when scaling down, and nearest neighbor when scaling up.

If C++ is preferred, the `scale` method in `Image` works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV [`resize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize) to do this. You should use INTER_NEAREST interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, the [`scaled` function](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qimage.html#scaled) of the `QImage` class gets the job done if you use the default parameter for the transformation method which is `Qt::FastTransformation`.